# Antd version update Error when updating from 4.13.1 to 5.6.3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I had updated my antd library in my react project from 4.13.1 to 5.6.3 version. I am getting the following error does anyone know how to resolve this?

Module not found: Can't resolve 'antd/es/auto-complete/style' in '/home/tanmay/projects'

I tried npm install deleting node_modules folder several times

Comment: Search for `antd/es/auto-complete/style` in your project and remove it. antd 5 uses css-in-js instead of styles. If it doesn't solve the problem, you need to create a code sandbox.

Comment: did you solve the issue op?